# Javascript: Change the value of an element in an array without mutating the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, immutability

Let's say I have an array in the form:

```
const array = [{id: 1, title: "this"}, {id: 2, title: "that"}];
```

I would like to change the value of one element in a given object. So that, for example, my output is like so:

> [{id: 1, title: "this"}, {id: 2, title: "foo foo foo"}];

I'm passing an object with two properties to my function. The first property is the **id** of the object I'd like to modify, and the second property is the **new title**:

```
[2, "foo foo foo"]
```

I'm able to find the index of the correct object using the following code:

```
index = array.findIndex(item => item.id === arr[0]);
```

But I can't figure out how to change the element and replace it with my new title (arr[1]).

I would like to change the title element in the second object ***without mutating the array***. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion regarding "without mutating the array". What I meant was I don't want the returned array to be simply a mutation of the original array, but rather a new array. Maybe "without mutating the *state*" would have been a better choice of words.

For example, if I were to return the an array like so:
    **return [...state]**
That would give me a new array (albeit with no changes) without mutating the original array.

Comment: post your function

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you not use something like `array.find(({id}) => id === arr[0]).title = arr[1]`? Technically this does not mutate the array as it is still the same with the same set of object references but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Does not `arr[index].title = "your new value"` work?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you mean by _"without mutating the array"_

Comment: @Phil: just edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really change an object without … well *mutating* it. You need a copy of the object. Assuming it's not going to cost to much to copy the array, you can do something like:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, title: "this"}, {id: 2, title: "that"}];
const a2 = arr.map(i => i.id == 2 ? Object.assign({}, i, {title: 'foo foo foo'}): i)

console.log("original: ", arr)
console.log("with changes: ", a2)
```

In this case, you are copying the original objects with the exception of the changed one, which gets a copy with the changes and leaves the original alone.

Comment: Great, that works. The reason I need a new array is because this is a Redux reducer, and if I'm not mistaken mutating the original array is discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `Array.map` function to iterate over the array and return the new array. In `map` function, check if the `id` is same as the `id passed in the arguments of the function`. If the condition is true, create a new object using `...(spread operators)`.

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, title: "this"}, {id: 2, title: "that"}];

var change = (id, title) => {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    if (obj.id === id) {
      return {...obj, title};
    }
    return obj;
  });
}

var arr2 = change(2, "foo foo foo");

console.log("original: ", arr);
console.log("with changes: ", arr2);
```

Comment: Be aware that object spreads (`{...object}`) are still not supported in Safari. This throws and error for me when I run the snippet.

Comment: Yes, It seems this is yet not implemented in Safari as yet (only in chrome & firefox) . Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Great, thanks for the solution. However I think I will go with Mark_M's solution as it utilizes ES6 and just seems a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "this"
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: "that"
}];

function replaceTitle(oldArray, [itemId, newTitle]) {
    let newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldArray));
    (newArray.find(({id}) => id === itemId) || {}).title = newTitle;
    return newArray;
}

const newArray = replaceTitle(array, [2, 'foo foo foo']);
console.log('ORIGINAL', array);
console.log('UPDATED', newArray);
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the OP said they didn't want to do? `array` has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't mutating the array. You are changing the property of an object contained in the array. The array stores references to your objects.

If you want to change an object in the array but still want to keep the original, you have to deep copy all of the objects being stored in the array.

Comment: Why do you need to deep copy *all* the objects in the array if you're only changing one?

Comment: Right, you don't need to deep copy all of the objects, just the one being changed. More efficient that way too. Unless you intend on modifying other objects at will, then you'll need to deep copy everything or you'll end up modifying the original array values.

Comment: The array is part of a Redux state, and I think I must return and entirely new array (as opposed to just deep copying and changing one object) else I will be mutating the state. Correct?